# Can't access a variable in my base class from a derived class

Tags: c#, inheritance, xna

I'm developing a mini game for a project using XNA and I have a base class called "Sprite.cs" that holds a position vector (`public Vector2 m_vPosition;`). I then have a derived class called "Player.cs". I have written a class for collision detection where a function takes in 2 sprite objects (where `gameObject` is also derived from Sprite.cs) and using the intersect function returns a true or false answer.

The problem is that when I step through the code, once it jumps into that collision detection function it shows that the position of my player is what it was set to on load, and doesn't change as I move the player around the screen even though outside of this function it shows that the position vector is working fine.

I believe my problem is that when I pass the player object into the function, it cannot access the base class (Sprite.cs) variables. Here are some code snippets.

Sprite.cs

```
public Vector2 m_vPosition;
public Rectangle m_rBoundingBox;
```

...

```
m_rBoundingBox = new Rectangle(
    (int)m_vPosition.X, 
    (int)m_vPosition.Y, 
    (int)(m_fWidth * m_fScale),
    (int)(m_fHeight * m_fScale));
```

Game1.cs

```
Player playerSprite;
playerSprite = new Player(); //where player is a child of sprite
```

...

```
if ((Collision.BoxtoBoxCollision(playerSprite, gameObject)))
            {
                playerSprite.m_vPosition = new Vector2(100, 100);
               //just testing to see if collision works, not collision logic.
            }
```

collision.cs

```
public bool BoxtoBoxCollision(Sprite objectOne, Sprite objectTwo)
    {
        if (objectOne.m_rBoundingBox.Intersects(objectTwo.m_rBoundingBox))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

So my problem is when i look at the position vector when `playerSprite` is passed into the collision function, it has not changed from when it first loaded.

If you need anymore information I'd be happy to supply more.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you update m_rBoundingBox of Player before calling BoxtoBoxCollision?

Comment: No, no I wasn't. Thankyou! Dont know why, just assumed it would get updated if my position was being updated :P stupid assumption. all good now, thanks.